# Firewall blocking Selenium but not browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, firewall, selenium

I'm trying to download a webpage using Selenium/Chrome driver. However, my firewall is blocking it (it's definitely the firewall because before it was implemented, I was able to download the webpage).

```
print("Getting webpage")
Browser.get(URL)
print("Downloaded webpage")
```

My script is stuck at `Getting webpage`, and after a while, it timeouts. However, if I use an actual browser, I'm able to load the webpage.

Is there a difference between using Selenium and an actual browser to access the webpage? Why is Selenium blocked but not the browser?

Comment: Have you double-checked the value of `URL` before it's called? Also, what do you mean by an "actual browser"? ChromeDriver should be controlling Chrome when running Selenium. You should have a normal browser window, unless you have specifically chosen to use Chrome in headless mode.

Comment: Yes, I used the exact URL for both Selenium and the browser. I am using  Chrome in headless mode, compared with running the Firefox browser and seeing the webpage load. But the difference in browser used should not be the problem, since Selenium/Chrome worked before the firewall was implemented.